# Does a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R_+},\mathbb{C}$ necessarily be $0$ at $\pm \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

if I have $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R_+};\mathbb{C})$ and want to study something like this

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty}f'(x)\overline{f(x)}\,dx
\end{equation}

Then I integrate by parts getting
\begin{equation}
|f(x)|^2 |_0^{\infty}-\int_0^\infty f(x)\overline{f'(x)} \,dx
\end{equation}

can I say that '$f(\infty)=0'$ if I know that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{C})$?

EDIT:

I'm sorry I meant that my $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{C})$ so it has weak derivative

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you cannot. Also, what does $f'$ mean for an $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{C})$? Most functions in this space not differentiable.

If however, you have that $f$ has an almost everywhere derivative $f'$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus holds, i.e. $f$ is locally absolutely continuous, and this derivative is also $L^2$, then you can argue as you have that  $|f(x)|^2$ has a limit, in which case yes it must be $0$.

Details: The argument is that since $f$ is weakly differentiable, and this weak derivative is also $L^2$, you have the existence of the following limit,
$$
\langle f,f'\rangle=\lim_{M\to \infty}\int_0^M f'(x)\overline{f(x)}\mathrm dx
$$
Now you integrate by parts and see that 
$$
\lim_{M\to \infty}\left(|f(x)|^2
\vert_0^M-\int_0^M f(x)\overline{f'(x)}\mathrm dx\right)
$$
must also exist, being equal to the first. But the second term has an existent limit, as again an inner product of $f$ and $f'$, so the first limit exists (why?). If it does, it must be zero (suppose it isn't, and $||f||_{L^2}$ is finite....).

Comment: I edited my question my f belongs to sobolev space $H^1$ so it has weak derivative in $L^2$. So in this case can I argue that it must have a limit and it is 0?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am referencing. Is this for a course in quantum mechanics out of curiosity?

Comment: but still I didn't understand why it must have a limit and it must be zero if it belongs to that sobolev space..

Comment: a.e. derivative does not imply locally AC

Comment: @zhw. of course, I was imprecise. I will edit

Comment: @zhw. When you have a chance, I believe it is worth responding to my edits in the above. As it stands, op doubts whether this answer suffices based on your of course valid comment (I believe now it is an adequate answer, but feel free to disagree) and this answer is in limbo until you respond.

Answer (score 0):

If $ f \in L^2 $, then it is not clear that $ f $ admits limit as $ x \to \infty $.

Comment: I thought that if $f \in L^2$ then the area underneath its graph should become zero sooner or later but then I thought that it would be the case of $f \in L^1..$